# how to remove double quote only from numeric data in a spark dataframe while writing it into a csv

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, numeric, quotes, double-quotes

While writing data into a csv from spark dataframe . I want to remove " quotes only from numeric data .

Actual Output:

```
+-------+---------+-----+
|user_id|course   |marks|
+-------+---------+-----+
|    "1"|    "eng"|  "9"|
|    "1"| "french"|  "7"|
+-------+---------+-- ---+
```

Expected Output

```
+-------+---------+-----+
|user_id|course   |marks|
+-------+---------+-----+
|      1|    "eng"|    9|
|      1| "french"|    7|
+-------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Could you post the CSV you used? When I'm trying on your data, I'm not getting the quotes around the numbers

Answer (score 0):

In DF, [cast](http://In%20DF,%20%20the%20numerical%20column%20Data%20type%20to%20Integer%20Type,%20df%20.select(df(%22user_id%22).cast(IntegerType),%20df(%22course%22),%20df(%22marks%22).cast(IntegerType))%20.show()) the numerical column Data type to Integer Type,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType

df
.select(df("user_id").cast(IntegerType), df("course"), df("marks").cast(IntegerType))
.show()
```

Comment: thanks for replying. please note here that I have some columns in decimal some in int. I cannot cast the columns to int.